# Tags count is not updated

Tags: discussion, tag-score

From the day we have the new user page look (very nice!!) I see that the tag count is not updated anymore.
In the previous days I thought I was wrong, but today I'm sure I received points in some tag (e.g. C#), but on that tag the count was not increased.

Is there any reason for not increasing it?

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one that noticed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114285/when-does-the-tag-score-get-updated-on-the-profile-page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In old user profile page layout, the tag counts were updated in almost real time. Since the dawn of new user profile page layout design, the tag counts are being updated only once a day *(my guess is around 3:00 am UTC based on what I have observed)*. I don't know the reason behind it but this functionality is similar to how `Top users` page works in every tag.

Comment: 3am (8pm MST) is about what I've observed too.  Pity, I miss those values being kept in real time.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Till 3AM (GMT+1) I had old count, but now at 8AM I had my score increased. Well, probably it was too heavy to update the score in real time with new design... Now we know. Thanks :)