# Tag counts on my profile do not update

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-score

The tag counts on my profile are not updated. You can verify it using the xml tag ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1108032%20%5Bxml%5D)), but it is even more true about my android tag.

I know there already exists [similar post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114362/tags-count-is-not-updated), but the solution there was "the tag counts are updated once a day". But in my case neither of the tag counts have been updated in the last 72 hours.